# How to call a Python function from a SQLite trigger

Tags: python, sqlite

This is my trigger

```py
cursor.execute(
 '''CREATE TRIGGER IF NOT EXISTS Car_Park_row_
    BEFORE INSERT ON Car_Park
    WHEN (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Car_PARK) >= 10
    BEGIN
        SELECT RAISE (ABORT, 'FULL');
        
        END;
```

and this is my function

```py
def C(x):
    print('Error')

# Create Database
connector = sqlite3.connect('cparks.db')
connector.create_function("sql", -1, C)
cursor = connector.cursor()
```

I've limited my rows on my database to 10 with the trigger. What I need now is a message box or something along the lines of to appear to let the GUI user know that the table is full.

Comment: def C (x):       
print (‘Error’) is the python function. 
I think it says ‘maximum number of rows reached’ in the terminal when the trigger fires can’t say exactly because I’m not at my computer but the trigger works. I just need a message box or something along the lines of to appear to let the gui user know that the table is full.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Executing the `RAISE()` function in a query raises a `sqlite3.IntegrityError` exception in the Python code which you can handle like any other exception.

Example script:

```
import sqlite3

db = sqlite3.connect(':memory:')
db.executescript('''
    CREATE TABLE car_park (car);

    CREATE TRIGGER car_park_row
    BEFORE INSERT ON car_park
    WHEN (SELECT count(*) FROM car_park) >= 10
    BEGIN
        SELECT RAISE (ABORT, 'full');
    END;
''')

for i in range(15):
    car = f'car{i}'
    try:
        res = db.execute('insert into car_park values (?)', (car,))
    except sqlite3.IntegrityError as e:
        print(f'Could not insert {car}: {e}')

for row in db.execute('SELECT * FROM car_park'):
    print(row)
```

Output:

```
Could not insert car10: full
Could not insert car11: full
Could not insert car12: full
Could not insert car13: full
Could not insert car14: full
('car0',)
('car1',)
('car2',)
('car3',)
('car4',)
('car5',)
('car6',)
('car7',)
('car8',)
('car9',)
```

(It may be advisable to `break` out of the loop if an error occurs, it is not done here just for demonstration purposes.)

Instead of printing an error message, you can call any Python function in the exception handler. You do not need to add a user-defined function to the database to do this:

```
def handle_insert_car_error(car, error):
    create_message_box(f'Could not insert {car}: {error}')  # or whatever
```

Then:

```
# ...
    try:
        res = db.execute('insert into car_park values (?)', (car,))
    except sqlite3.IntegrityError as e:
        handle_insert_car_error(car, e)
```

Comment: That is a beautiful pythonic way to do this! Thanks for this answer @mkrieger1!